# Cryptographic hashing class using OpenSSL's EVP interface

Tags: c++, c++17, cryptography, openssl

I have written a cryptographic hashing class named `Ccksum::DigestHasher` that allows the caller to select a hashing algorithm by name via OpenSSL's EVP interface. This class is the bread and butter of my [Ccksum](https://gitlab.com/app-crypt/ccksum) programming project. Here is the code so far (I combined the header and source files for the readability of this post. I also removed all documentation comments, because I believe the code speaks for itself):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace Ccksum {
class Hasher {
public:
    explicit Hasher() = default;
    virtual ~Hasher() noexcept = default;
    virtual std::string process(std::istream& input) const = 0;
    virtual std::string name() const = 0;
};

class DigestHasher final : public Hasher {
public:
    explicit DigestHasher(const std::string& name)
        : m_context(EVP_MD_CTX_new(), EVP_MD_CTX_free)
        , m_algorithm(EVP_get_digestbyname(name.c_str()))
        , m_name(name)
    {
        if (m_context == nullptr) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Cannot create hash algorithm context");
        }

        if (m_algorithm == nullptr) {
            std::ostringstream errorMsg;
            errorMsg << name << " is not a valid hash algorithm";
            throw std::runtime_error(errorMsg.str());
        }
    }

    ~DigestHasher() noexcept override = default;

    std::string process(std::istream& input) const override
    {
        if (!input.good()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Input stream is bad");
        }

        constexpr size_t bufferSize = 65536; // 64K seems good...
        std::vector<char> buffer(bufferSize);
        std::vector<unsigned char> hash(EVP_MD_size(m_algorithm));

        if (EVP_DigestInit_ex(m_context.get(), m_algorithm, nullptr) == 0) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Cannot initialize hash algorithm");
        }

        while (input.good()) {
            input.read(buffer.data(), bufferSize);
            if (EVP_DigestUpdate(m_context.get(), buffer.data(), input.gcount()) == 0) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Cannot update hash context");
            }
        }

       if (EVP_DigestFinal_ex(m_context.get(), hash.data(), nullptr) == 0) {
           throw std::runtime_error("Cannot finalize hash context");
       }

       std::ostringstream formatHash;
       formatHash << std::hex << std::setfill('0');

       for (const auto& iterate : hash) {
           formatHash << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned int>(iterate);
       }

        return formatHash.str();
    }

    std::string name() const override
    {
        return m_name;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<EVP_MD_CTX, decltype(&EVP_MD_CTX_free)> m_context;
    const EVP_MD* m_algorithm;
    const std::string m_name;
};
} // Ccksum namespace
```

**NOTE:** The `Ccksum::Hasher` abstract class exists for mocking purposes. My plan is to mock `Ccksum::DigestHasher` using `Ccksum::Hasher` to make it easier to unit test the `Ccksum::GenerateMode` class I am currently working on.

**Question 1:** Should I wrap `m_algorithm` in a `std::unique_ptr` or leave it the way it is?

**Current rationale regarding question 1:** I left `m_algorithm` as a raw const pointer of type `EVP_MD`, because the [example code](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/EVP_DigestInit_ex.html#EXAMPLE) offered by OpenSSL's docs does not show freeing its `EVP_MD` variable, nor did I find any kind of `EVP_MD_free()` function. A [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605731/need-to-free-evp-md-from-evp-sha256) states that there is no need to free `EVP_MD` at all. As a sanity check, I ran my code through valgrind and no memory leaks were found.

**EDIT 1:** I changed the `bufferSize` constant to 64KB. This [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc938632(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) states that a buffer size of 64KB is a reasonable default for modern desktops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks quite good already. However, some improvements can be made:

## Avoid unnecessary use of `stringstream`s

String streams are quite heavy, so using it to build small strings is perhaps not the way to go. Instead of:

```
std::ostringstream errorMsg;
errorMsg << name << " is not a valid hash algorithm";
throw std::runtime_error(errorMsg.str());
```

You can just write:

```
throw std::runtime_error(name + " is not a valid hash algorithm");
```

With C++20 (or using the [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library for older versions of the C++ standard), you can [format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) strings the C way, but in a type-safe way:

```
throw std::runtime_error(std::format("{} is not a valid hash algorithm", name));
```

## Incomplete error checking

`process()` is checking the state of the input string right at the start of the function, but then ignores any errors that might happen later on. What you should do is check that `input.eof()` is `true` after the `while`-loop; you can even omit the check at the start.

## Return the raw hash value

`process()` calculates the hash *and* converts it to a hexadecimal string. But what if I just want to convert two hash values, which can be done more efficiently if they were just in the original binary encoding? Or what if I need the hash in base64 format? I would apply the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) design principle, and just let `process()` return a `std::vector<unsigned char>` (even better, use [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) instead of `unsigned char`). Let the caller worry about converting it to other representations if so desired.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I will update my code base and the code of my post to reflect your recommendations.

Comment: @g-sliepen I forgot to ask, when you state to check `input.eof()` after the while loop, would it also be correct to replace `while (input.good())` with `while (!input.eof())` instead of checking for `input.eof()` after while?

Comment: @JasonPena No, because you might encounter an error before reaching the end of the file. The `while`-loop should just check if it makes sense to try to `read()` some more, after the loop you check whether you have really read all of the input. Also: don't edit your post, if you want updated code to be reviewed, just create a new question!

Comment: @g-sliepen Okay, so I check for `input.eof()` after the while loop and throw if it is not true as a replacement for the original sanity check at the start of `process()`. Thanks!